# Sorting "About Us" Page

Tags: sort, publish-layout

I'm using "v2.9.2 - Build Date: 20141004" of EE and currently have an "About Us" page where I have a photo of company staff.

Currently the only way to put this into a desired order is to change the "Date Uploaded" to an arbitrary value that corresponds with the desired order as they are sorted by that.

This seems a bit bonkers and I was hoping I could just enter a custom ordering field and sort on that?

Comment: Do you mean you have photo**s** of your companies staff members, so you therefore have a channel entry for each staff member, and you'd like to sort your channel entries in a certain way?

Comment: We've always just opted to order by date and edit those, a little annoying but it works and is accessible to those who don't have template/addon access. Another way we've also acheived ordering for company staff is statuses/categories based on heirachy.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [Low Reorder](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-reorder), which provides a nice interface to reordering entries, but if you want a basic implementation, have a custom field (for example `order`) with a number in it, then have parameters in your channel:entries tag for `orderby="order" sort="asc"`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [order by channel field](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby). Alternatively you could hardcode the channel tag to show specific entries, like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries ... entry_id="13|42|147" ...}
```

Comment: Trouble is when specifying specific entries, when you add a new member of staff, most clients can't (or don't have access to) the templates, so the new member isn't added and the developer needs to modify it, so not very flexible when you have a CMS.

Comment: Fair point, but we don't really know the OP's needs. That said, the orderby= parameter really should do what he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already provided. You could also create the content for ABOUT US as a single entry and add a [Grid field](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/grid.html) for employees (with grid field options for bio, photo, contact details, etc), and then your client can drag and drop the employees (Grid rows) to change display order.

This might not be the best solution for all cases (for example, if you need to separate employee info to other parts of the site), but it does allows the client to see/edit all employee info within the one entry and doesn't require editing multiple entries, or visiting another area of the CP to effect ordering.